e.which? e.keyCode?
Para que serve esse trecho de codigo? não entendo muito bem. Sei que se refere a um botão como se tivesse testando um ou outro, estou certo ou errado?

    const key = e.which || e.keyCode



Ambas propriedades, which e keyCode servem para obter a tecla, se executada dentro do evento keypress, keydown ou keyup. No entanto ambos são obsoletas. Para tirar dúvidas do tipo consulte sempre a documentação, sobre CSS, HTML e JS o local é o site MDN, segue links úteis: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/which; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Para responder especificamente sobre o trecho, o sinal || é o OR/ou, usado na lógica, se which não é suportado pelo navegador, então o resultado será falsy, o que fará a lógica testar o próximo, que no caso é o keyCode. Leia mais em: O que são os valores truthy e falsy?
